# why does the car teleport to my waypoints

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a code that allows a car to drive to defined waypoints, if it arrives there it automaticly drives to the next. Following code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class AICar : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform Player;
    public Transform Player2;
    public Transform Player3;
    public Transform Player4;
    public Transform Player5;
    public Transform Player6;
    public int MoveSpeed = 5;
    int MaxDist = 10;
    int MinDist = 5;




    void Start()
  {
      StartCoroutine(SparseUpdate());
  }

  IEnumerator SparseUpdate()
  {
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
      while(true)
      {
          yield return null;


          transform.LookAt(Player);
          if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) >= MinDist)
          {
              transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
              Debug.Log(MoveSpeed);
              if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) <= MaxDist)
              {
                  StartCoroutine(SparseUpdateSecond());
              }
          // Do all the normal things you'd do in Update here instead.
      }
   }
 }
    IEnumerator SparseUpdateSecond()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
        while(true)
        {
            yield return null;


            transform.LookAt(Player2);
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player2.position) >= MinDist)
            {
                transform.position += transform.forward *  * Time.deltaTime;
                Debug.Log(MoveSpeed);
                if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) <= MaxDist)
                {
                  StartCoroutine(SparseUpdateThird());
                }
            // Do all the normal things you'd do in Update here instead.
        }
       }
    }

    IEnumerator SparseUpdateThird()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
        while(true)
        {
            yield return null;


            transform.LookAt(Player3);
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player3.position) >= MinDist)
            {
                transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player3.position) <= MaxDist)
                {
                  StartCoroutine(SparseUpdateFourth());
                }
            // Do all the normal things you'd do in Update here instead.
        }
       }
    }

    IEnumerator SparseUpdateFourth()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
        while(true)
        {
            yield return null;


            transform.LookAt(Player4);
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player4.position) >= MinDist)
            {
                transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player4.position) <= MaxDist)
                {
                  StartCoroutine(SparseUpdateFifht());

                }
            // Do all the normal things you'd do in Update here instead.
        }
       }
    }

    IEnumerator SparseUpdateFifht()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
        while(true)
        {
            yield return null;


            transform.LookAt(Player5);
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player5.position) >= MinDist)
            {
                transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player5.position) <= MaxDist)
                {
                  StartCoroutine(SparseUpdateSixt());

                }
            // Do all the normal things you'd do in Update here instead.
        }
       }
    }

        IEnumerator SparseUpdateSixt()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
            while(true)
            {
                yield return null;


                transform.LookAt(Player6);
                if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player6.position) >= MinDist)
                {
                    transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player6.position) <= MaxDist)
                    {


                    }
                // Do all the normal things you'd do in Update here instead.
            }
           }
        }




  }
```

it drives slowly to the first, which is right but to the others it is very quick and i dont know why? can anbyody help?
thank you

I tried other methods to move the car but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, place debugger around to see how your code actually works do miracles!

In this one though, since each of your IEnumerator placed inside a *while(true)*, it simply doesnt stop and ends up running *all* the IEnumerators at the same time.

In sort, just include a break; after each time you start new coroutine, something like this should do

```
if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player3.position) >= MinDist)
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player3.position) <= MaxDist)
            {
              StartCoroutine(SparseUpdateFourth());
              break;
            }
        // Do all the normal things you'd do in Update here instead.
```